# How to create child records of custom object type on parent record detail?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I am newbie on salesforce platform. I have been learning through salesforce trailhead. Based on it, I have created two custom object called `Applications` and `Payment Quotes` by point and click . Both objects have one-many relationships that means Application can have multiple Quotes.

When I create new application , I also want to create multiple Quotes for that application.

How can I achieve it ? Do I need to create VisualForce pages and apex classes or It can be done by simple point and click.

It should be like any action button on Application record which allows me to create new Quote (by opening pop up type of form for Quote) and add to that application.

Please guide me on this. Are there any other work around to achieve my goal?

Thank you.

Comment: Trailhead's [Process Automation](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/business_process_automation) and [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_triggers) modules will teach you multiple ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using point and click by creating a junction object and then relating x quote to y application and y application to z quote . With Custom UI you can make it whatever you wanted to achieve but keep in mind without any relationship or any key you are telling system to search a grain from pack of rice which is a not a good design . This is a simple ask all depends on what approach you wanted to take.

Comment: Try using filters to only restrict the quote specific to a  application ID .